# Jquery mobile data-?

Tags: jquery, html, validation

Is data-theme or data-role belong to html5?
If it isn't belong html how browser render it without knowing this attribute?
Can I add a new attribute to html document and say browser "render this like that" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-mobile-what-can-it-do-for-you/) is telling that:

> data- attributes are a wonderful new feature of HTML5 that let you add
>   any attributes you like to an element. All you have to do is start
>   your attribute name with the data- prefix.